# Test at runtime if a passed in ByRef parameter shares storage location with a given "other" variable

Tags: c#, .net, pass-by-reference, ref, byref

This question is more out of curiosity than out of a practical need.

Is there any way one can test if the argument passed in to a `ByRef` (that is `ref` or `out` in C#) parameter has the same storage location as some "other" variable? I don't mean to test if the objects are identical, since two distinct reference variables might be two distinct references to the same object.

I've come up with some examples to explain what I mean. Consider:

```
public static void SillySwap(ref int a, ref int b)
{
  // first put sum of original numbers into slot a,
  // then use that to get out the original numbers swapped
  a = a + b;
  b = a - b;
  a = a - b;
}
```

(We would normally use a third temporary variable instead, but to illustrate my question I do it like this.) `SillySwap` works fine if you come in with *two* variables, either identical or different in numerical value. But if you call it like so:

```
int shared = 42;
SillySwap(ref shared, ref shared);
```

it will annihilate `shared`. **Is there any way I could test inside the body of `SillySwap` if `a` and `b` are equal as storage locations?**

Here's a modified example with a field ("class variable"):

```
protected static int field;
public static void SillySwap2(ref int arg)
{
  arg = arg + field;
  field = arg - field;
  arg = arg - field;
}
```

Here we want to check if the `arg` passed in was actually the variable `field`.

For a final example, consider this:

```
static bool SillyTryGetStrings(out string first, out string second)
{
  // the order of assignment may matter here!
  second = "world";
  first = "Hello";

  return true;
}
```

Suppose some strange person passes in the same variable for `first` and `second`. Can we check for that inside the method?

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use unsafe code and compare pointers to variables:

```
public unsafe bool AreRefsEqual(ref int a, ref int b)
{
    fixed (int* aptr = &a)
    fixed (int* bptr = &b)
    {
        return aptr == bptr;
    }         
}

[TestMethod]
public void ShouldRefsEqualWork()
{
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    Assert.IsTrue(AreRefsEqual(ref a, ref a));
    Assert.IsFalse(AreRefsEqual(ref a, ref b));           
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. Can your `unsafe` method be made generic to work with all value types and reference types, not just `int`?

Comment: I don't think it can be done in c#, as you cannot take the address of generic type no matter the constraints (you can only take address of few types). I think it would be possible in C++/CLI though.

Comment: So your solution is only partial. It has some limitations. (1) It only works for value types (and only value types that don't have instance fields of reference types). (2) It is legal to take the address with the unary `&` operator of an unassigned variable, I think, so if I have an `out int i` parameter and want to check its address in the beginning, I can use your code "inline", but I don't think it will allow me to pass `i` on to your `AreRefsEqual` method because it is not definitely assigned.